# pandas transpose numeric column by group

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, pivot-table, transpose

code to make test data

```
import pandas as pd

dftest = pd.DataFrame({'Amt': {0: 60, 1: 35.0, 2: 30.0, 3: np.nan, 4: 25},
                       'Year': {0: 2012.0, 1: 2012.0, 2: 2012.0, 3: 2013.0, 4: 2013.0},
                       'Name': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'C', 3: 'A', 4: 'B'}})
```

gives

```
    Amt     Name    Year
0   60        A   2012.0
1   35.0      A   2012.0
2   30.0      C   2012.0
3   NaN       A   2013.0
4   25        B   2013.0
```

column `Amt` has max 2 values corresponding to group `['Name', 'Year']`. I would like to pivot/transpose such that output is of the form

```
       Name  Year   Amt1  Amt2
0         A  2012   35    60
2         C  2012   30    NaN
3         A  2013   NaN   NaN
4         B  2013   25    NaN
```

I have tried playing with pivot, unstack, pivot_table

what I really want to do is to ensure there are two values of `Amt` per `['Name', 'Year']` (`NA`'s are OK), which I can achieve by stacking the desired output

Comment: I would have guessed you'd want Amt1 to be 60 and Amt2 to be 35 for the first row.  Do you want them sorted first?

Comment: I'd prefer them to be sorted ascending, which being trivial, I guess you can neglect it for now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `groupby` and `apply`

```
f = lambda x: x.sort_values(ascending=True).reset_index(drop=True)
dftest.groupby(['Name', 'Year']).Amt.apply(f).unstack()
```

[image]